# Trouble while building GCC compiler

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

So, I am trying to build the GCC compiler (8.1.0) from source, and I ran into a problem. I am trying to build it on Windows 7 and first, I tried building the 8.2.0 version and encountered the exact problem with the current version I am trying to build (figured since the 8.2.0 version came out on 26th of July, two weeks before posting this question, it had an issue :) ).

The first thing I am doing is configuring for the build process, with the following:

```
configure --program-suffix=-8.1.0. --enable-languages=c --disable-bootstrap --disable-shared --prefix="C:\Users\Vuk\Desktop\Diplomski\gcc-8.1.0\objdir"
```

I have previously made an objdir directory as it is recommended by the official [guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html). In which I plan to store the built compiler.

After the previous step i run:

> make -j4

which leads to a few minutes of compiling and the 1st error message:

```
    ../../intl/localealias.c: In function ‘_nl_expand_alias’:
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: error: incomplete universal character name \U
     locale_alias_path = LOCALE_ALIAS_PATH;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\V'
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\D'
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\D'
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\g'
../../intl/localealias.c:164:25: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\o'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:133: localealias.o] Error 1
```

Eventually, the second error message appears along with a gigantic wall of text which I can't display:

```
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Vuk/Desktop/Diplomski/gcc-8.1.0/objdir/libiberty'
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating backtrace-supported.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing gstdint.h commands
config.status: executing default commands
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Vuk/Desktop/Diplomski/gcc-8.1.0/objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:889: all] Error 2
```

I am not doing all of this from the windows command line, instead, I am using cygwin64.

Comment: `"C:\Users\Vuk\Desktop\Diplomski\gcc-8.1.0\objdir"` somehow ends up in the source code (probably via macros) and causes trouble because `\U`, `\V`, `\D`, `\g`, `\o` are not valid backslash escape sequences in strings.

Comment: @melpomene you are completely right. And I find it funny that I didn't notice that \U , \V ,... correspond to the path I was compiling to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the original path

```
"C:\Users\Vuk\Desktop\Diplomski\gcc-8.1.0\objdir"
```

with

```
"C:/Users/Vuk/Desktop/Diplomski/gcc-8.1.0/objdir"
```

solves the problem.